# Finding out with GUI toolkit was used?

Tags: user-interface

This may be the wrong place...but since it's actually regarding a GUI toolkit I figured it might be appropriate here.

Anyways theres a Program (For anyones reference it's actually an automated modding thing for a game called Morrowind). Anyways it has a nice clean GUI layout, it's for Windows. And basically im trying to find out just what toolkit was used.

I've tried contacting the author, and I haven't seen anything about what was used mentioned anywhere. Is there any chance I could find out someway which toolkit was used in making this Program?

Or is that technically private information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program runs on MS-Windows, [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) allows you to find out which libraries the program requires. The required libraries might give you a hint about which GUI toolkit was used.

On other platforms, [ldd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldd_%28Unix%29) is often available and gives you similar information.

This only works if the GUI toolkit is dynamically linked.